# Making my activity wait until i receive my GPS coordinates. (Android, AsyncTask)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, gps

I want to make my activity wait unti the GPS locates the user, and only then move to "new RemoteDataTask().execute();". Is there any way i can do that? I tried with do () while, Thread.sleep, etc. They work, but slow down gravely my coordinates receiving process. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Here is my class where is use the Location Service:
    package com.fourbox.bocterapp;

```
//declarations

public class RecentSightings extends Activity {

//more declarations


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(com.fourbox.bocterapp.R.layout.recent_sightings_design);

        if (getIntent().hasExtra("currentUserLatitude")) {
            currentUserLatitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("currentUserLatitude", 0);
            currentUserLongitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("currentUserLongitude", 0);
        }


        locationManager = (LocationManager) RecentSightings.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            if (currentUserLatitude==0) {
                MyLocation.LocationResult locationResult = new MyLocation.LocationResult() {
                    @Override
                    public void gotLocation(Location location) {
                        currentUserLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                        currentUserLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                };
                MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
                myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait until we get your coordinates!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            showGPSDisabledAlertToUser();
        }


                new RemoteDataTask().execute();

    }

        private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RecentSightings.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading recent sightings");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("AlertsClass");
            query.orderByDescending("_created_at");

            try {
                ob = query.find();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(com.fourbox.bocterapp.R.id.alertListView);
            Location currentUserLocation = new Location("currentUserLocation");
            currentUserLocation.setLatitude(currentUserLatitude);
            currentUserLocation.setLongitude(currentUserLongitude);
            getDataForListView();
            CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(RecentSightings.this, com.fourbox.bocterapp.R.layout.list_item, alertsList, currentUserLocation);
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);


            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            // Capture button clicks on ListView items
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // Send single item click data to SingleItemView Class
                    Intent i = new Intent(RecentSightings.this,
                            AlertViewOnMap.class);
                    // Pass data "name" followed by the position
                    i.putExtra("coordinatesLatitude", alertsList.get(position).getCoordinates().getLatitude());
                    i.putExtra("coordinatesLongitude", alertsList.get(position).getCoordinates().getLongitude());
                    i.putExtra("description", alertsList.get(position).getDescription());
                    i.putExtra("busNumber", alertsList.get(position).getBusNumber());
                    i.putExtra("createdAt", alertsList.get(position).getCreatedAt().getTime());
                    i.putExtra("currentUserLatitude", currentUserLatitude);
                    i.putExtra("currentUserLongitude", currentUserLongitude);      
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("busNumberList", busNumberList);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("descriptionList", descriptionList);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("coordinatesLatitudeList", coordinatesLatitudeList);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("coordinatesLongitudeList", coordinatesLongitudeList);
                    i.putStringArrayListExtra("dateCreatedAtList", dateCreatedAtList);


                    // Open SingleItemView.java Activity
                    startActivity(i);

                }


            });


        }
    }
```

Anticipated thanks for the help! Cheers.

Edit #1: Added MyLocation Class:

```
package com.fourbox.bocterapp;

/**
 * Created by Soulstorm on 10/14/2014.
 */


public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //I use LocationResult callback class to pass location value from MyLocation to user code.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //exceptions will be thrown if provider is not permitted.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //don't start listeners if no provider is enabled
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,     locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 50000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
            Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
            if(gps_enabled)
                gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            if(network_enabled)
                net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            //if there are both values use the latest one
            if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                else
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }

            if(gps_loc!=null){
                locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                return;
            }
            if(net_loc!=null){
                    locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                return;
            }
            locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just move the execute call in the gotLocation callback you already have ?

```
public void gotLocation(Location location) {
   currentUserLatitude = location.getLatitude();
   currentUserLongitude = location.getLongitude();
   new RemoteDataTask().execute();
}
```

You may need to post the MyLocation class to make sure I'm getting how this works.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will do.

Comment: It worked. Oh my god man. It was so simple... I love you! Sending beer through email right now.